# VSCode Marketplace Does Not Load

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have recently downloaded VSCode, but my most basic functions were not working due to "cannot edit in read-only editor" error. Thank to stack overflow I fixed the issue by changing code runner settings and enabling  editing through the terminal. Then I tried to move the program  from downloads folder to applications, when suddenly the extensions marketplace stopped loading. When I go to "Help" --> "Toggle Developers Tools" --> "Console", I see two messages:

[image]

I am using MacBook Pro (2020) and have no idea what to do. I am very new to programming and would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is gonna help, but you can reinstall VSCode again, this time put the app in the Applications folder. If the marketplace doesn't load maybe it cannot connect to the DNS, try to change the DNS address to google's `8.8.8.8`.
Also, take a look at this, it seems similar to your issue. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/54033

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, changing the DNS address did not help and VSCode is already downloaded to applications folder. I have reinstalled VSCode multiple times but something is missing. Based on the error messages in the developers tools, I think the problem is with API and 'configuration.jsonValidation.url'